# Prove that if $\angle{DAC} = \angle{ABE}$, then $\angle{AFC} = \angle{ADB}$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be a triangle and points $D$, $E$ and $F$ be the midpoints of $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$, respectively. Prove that if $\angle{DAC} = \angle{ABE}$, then  $\angle{AFC} = \angle{ADB}$.

I tried drawing the lines $DE$, $FE$ and $DF$, since each segment would be parallel to one of the sides of the triangle, but this didn't help. I also tried to use the $\displaystyle \frac{a \cdot b 
\cdot \sin{C}}{2}$ formula for the area of the triangle, since the medians divide a triangle in six smaller triangles of equal area and there are equal angles, but this didn't help much either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medians meet at the centroid $G$. $DF$ is parallel to $AC$, so $∠FDG = ∠DAC$ (alternate angles) = $∠ABE$ (given) = $∠FBG$ (same angle). So $FGDB$ is cyclic. So $∠ADB = ∠GDB$ (same angle) = $180^° - ∠GFB = ∠AFC$.